# How to grep current word under cursor in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to grep current word under cursor in emacs. I have written code below, which throws the error: Wrong number of arguments... When I remove (grep) from xx() and bind it to f4 key (commented last line), after f3 and f4 grep searches word under cursor. Does any one know why (grep) can not be called from xx()?
Thanks, Alex.

```
(require 'grep)
(defun xx ()
  "setting up grep-command using current word under cursor as a search string"
 (interactive)
 (setq curWord (thing-at-point 'word))
 (setq VALUE   (concat "grep -nH -r --exclude='TAGS' --include='*.h' --include='*.cpp' --include='*.pl' --include='*.c' -e " curWord " /home/alex/code/") )
 (grep-apply-setting 'grep-command VALUE)
 (grep))

 (global-set-key (kbd "<f3>")  'xx)
;(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") 'grep )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grep` function takes one argument, so change your function to pass it:

```
(defun xx ()
  "setting up grep-command using current word under cursor as a search string"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((cur-word (thing-at-point 'word))
         (cmd (concat "grep -nH -r --exclude='TAGS' --include='*.h' --include='*.cpp' --include='*.pl' --include='*.c' -e " cur-word " /home/alex/code")))
    (grep-apply-setting 'grep-command cmd)
    (grep cmd)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change the `grep` command or define your own replacement. You just need to grab the default value that it provides, which is already the word at point.

1. You should be able to use `M-n` to retrieve the word at point, after you use `M-x grep`.  (But be careful to put back the switches. Apparently vanilla Emacs removes them when you hit `M-n`.)

   `M-n` inserts the default value of a command into the minibuffer at the prompt. If there are multiple default values then repeating `M-n` cycles among them. This is true in general, not just for command `grep`.
2. If you use library [Grep+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepPlus) then the default value is automatically inserted into the minibuffer (without changing the command switches). And you have more control over just what you want the default value and other default behaviors to be.

Answer (score 0):

If using `counsel-projectile` https://github.com/ericdanan/counsel-projectile, set `counsel-projectile-grep-initial-input`, `counsel-projectile-ag-initial-input`, or `counsel-projectile-rg-initial-input` to option "Symbol or selection at point"